# Import class from another namespace dynamically

Tags: php, php-7

I'm trying to load classes from another namespace dynamically, I can do this if I know the class but if I want to pass the class name in as a string I can't get it to work.

**This works statically:**

```
namespace Foo;

use Bar;

$obj = new Bar\SomeClassFromBar();
```

**This does not work dynamically:**

```
namespace Foo;

use Bar;

$class = 'SomeClassFromBar';

$obj = new Bar\$class();
```

Is this possible using PHP7?

Comment: did you tried this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you may do this as follows:

```
namespace Foo;

$class = 'SomeClassFromBar';

$stdClass = "\\Bar\\" . $class;

$obj = new $stdClass();
```

[full example :](https://3v4l.org/XTpS7)

```
namespace Bar {
    class SomeClassFromBar
    {
        public function __construct()
        {
            echo __CLASS__ . "\n";
        }
    }
}

namespace Foo {
    $class = 'SomeClassFromBar';

    $stdClass = "\\Bar\\" . $class;

    $obj = new $stdClass();

    // Output : Bar\SomeClassFromBar
}
```